# Getting the real Location of mouse in actual size of image, not the location of mouse in PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, mouseevent, picturebox

I have a image with size of 1278 X 958, I am doing some image processing on that.

As the image size is big,I load it with following command in a pictureBox:

```
imGrayShow = cap.QueryGrayFrame();
picBOriginal.Image = imGrayShow.ToBitmap();
```

pictureBox size is 299 X 204 and to see my original image in pictureBox I put the

**pictureBox Size Mode= StretchImage**

The story starts here:

I want to use **mouse-down & mouse-up event** to get the location of the area that the user selects with following command:

```
 private void picBOriginal_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (stopEventMouseDrag == true)
            {
                endP = e.Location;

                if (startP != endP)
                {
                    stopEventMouseDrag = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void picBOriginal_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (stopEventMouseDrag == true)
            {
                startP = e.Location;
            }
        }
```

What I get as the **startP** and **endP** is **(145,2)** and **(295,83)** respectively; but these are the location of mouse in pictureBox, whereas I am expecting to find out the real location of mouse down and mouse down in my original Image. 
( which are=> startP: **890,1** endP: **1277,879** )

how could I possibly get the REAL location of startP-endP in the original Image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your math is a bit off.  If you have a 1278 x 958 image and you want to scale it down to 299 pixels wide, then you need to divide everything by `1278 / 299` which is **4.27**.  To keep the aspect ratio the same, the width would need to be `958 / 4.27` which rounds to **224**.

Then when you receive the coordinates from the mouse down & up events, you just multiply the coordinates by **4.27** to scale up the values to the original image.

Comment: That is so neat, Is it still okay if I keep my pictureSize mode in stretchImage?

Comment: Some addition to what David told. The multiplication factor for the width is: 4.27 and for height is 4.69

Answer (score 1):

startP and endP are point relative to your picture box, or relative to the screen? From what I remember, the `Location` in a `MouseEventArgs` is relative to the form, which isn't very useful.

So... It would probably end up something like this:

```
// Position of the mouse, relative to the upper left corner of the picture box.
Point controlRelative = myPictureBox.PointToClient(MousePosition);
// Size of the image inside the picture box
Size imageSize = myPictureBox.Image.Size;
// Size of the picture box
Size boxSize = myPictureBox.Size;

Point imagePosition = new Point((imageSize.Width / boxSize.Width) * controlRelative.X,
                                (imageSize.Height / boxSize.Height) * controlRelative.Y);
```

Comment: well, the event assumes the pictureBox area so it is relative to pictureBox

Comment: Then, just skip the first line and use the event data in the last one.